# Can text-shadow be removed from vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In vscode under Centos linux 7.4 there are text-shadows in some interface elements. Anyone know how to remove the text-shadow?

I tried adding the following to the user settings css this but it does not work:

"*" : {
        "text-shadow": 0
    },

[image: Screenshot of text-shadow]

Comment: That looks like the system file dialog, not VS Code

Comment: Yes, it does look like a system file dialog. But the text shadow happens only in vscode. Other programs like Gimp and Meld don't have the text shadow.